# How to make Windows display application crashes in the console?

Tags: windows, crash

I'm developping a C application on Windows 7 64 bits, and each time it crashes I get the following dialog:

[image]

I would prefer something more "old school" with the complete error dumped in the console.

Something like

```
> HelloWorld
The application has crashed in somedll.dll for some Horrible C reason.
I have an error code 0x4445506
And a kinda stacktrace
And walls of hexa 
0x4445506 0x4445506 0x4445506 0x4445506 0x4445506
0x4445506 0x4445506 0x4445506 0x4445506 0x4445506
0x4445506 0x4445506 0x4445506 0x4445506 0x4445506
0x4445506 0x4445506 0x4445506 0x4445506 0x4445506
0x4445506 0x4445506 0x4445506 0x4445506 0x4445506
0x4445506 0x4445506 0x4445506 0x4445506 0x4445506
```

Is there a way to get that?

Should I run my application with a command line debugger ?

Note: should I post this on Stackoverflow instead?